# Normalizations that satisfy Restrictions: Unique?

Tags: normalization

I am trying to implement a paper, and at some point I ran across the following:

> (...) where both $\phi$ and $\phi^*$ have been normalized so that $\mathrm{E}[\phi^2(g)]=1$ and $\mathrm{E}[\phi(g)\phi^*(g)]=1$.

In this context, $\phi$ and $\phi^*$ are functions on $g$ that map to $\mathbb{R}$.

**Question**: Is there a unique normalization that accomplishes both $\mathrm{E}[\phi^2(g)]=1$ and $\mathrm{E}[\phi(g)\phi^*(g)]=1$? If so, what is it?

**More details**: I tried doing the standard normalization (subtract mean and divide by standard deviation) for $\phi$ and $\phi^*$, which gives me $\mathrm{E}[\phi^2(g)]=1$, but **not** necessarily $\mathrm{E}[\phi(g)\phi^*(g)]=1$.

Thanks for helping! :D

Comment: Perhaps by "normalized" the paper means in the sense of a vector, which is simply rescaled?  (In that case the normalization is almost, but not quite, unique: you can simultaneously multiply $\phi$ and $\phi^{*}$ by $-1$.)

Comment: I agree. The paper is doing some kind of rescaling, but it is not clear how. And depending on how you rescale the function you will get a different result, so I was wondering if there is a standard way of doing this "normalization", since he does not mention anything at all anywhere in the paper.

Comment: Yes: "normalize" has a standard meaning when one is talking about vectors--and another *almost* standard meaning when a statistician is talking about data or distributions!  I believe that careful authors distinguish between "standardizing" and "normalizing" for just this reason.  Your question appears to revolve around your interpretation of "normalize" as "standardize."  I can't see how we could contribute to the answer: you need to examine the context of the paper and choose the interpretation that makes sense.